# NodeJS docs generator

Tags: linux, open-source, javascript, node.js

I need a NodeJS based generator that takes as input a JavaScript file and generate markdown documentation.

Example:

```
/**
 * foo
 * foo description
 *
 * @name foo
 * @param {String} a Some description
 * @param {Object} b An object param
 * @return {Boolean} Some foo again
 */
function foo (a, b) {
   /* do something */
   return Boolean(...);
}
```

The result will be something like this:

```
## foo (a, b)
foo description
  - `a` (String): Some description
  - `b` (Object): An object param
Returns (Boolean) Some foo again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [`markdox`](https://github.com/cbou/markdox) library, I created a [command line tool named `blah` that does this task](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-blah).

To install it do:

```
$ npm install -g blah
```

To generate a markdown documentation for a js file:

```
$ blah docs your-file.js
```

This will create `DOCUMENTATION.md` file. For more information check out the [blog post](http://ionicabizau.net/blog/13-introducing-blah-command-line-tool) and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-blah).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it generates exactly the output you're looking for (and that might be hard to find), but [JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) follows your other needs: JS doc generator, in node.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer – but unfortunately, this post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a program that directly generates markdown doc. Until somebody makes it, you can generate a html doc that's as simple as possible and then convert it to markdown. Here's a tool to do the conversion

http://domchristie.github.io/to-markdown/